# Do I need a transit visa in JFK en route to St. Kitts and Nevis?

Tags: usa, transit, nigerian-citizens

I'm Nigerian, passing through JFK on Delta Air on my way to St. Kitts and Nevis on tourist visa on arrival policy. I want to know if it is possible without a transit visa.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, you need a visa.  It could be a transit visa (C) or a visitor visa (B).  All passengers in the US, including transit passengers, must clear immigration controls, and the US did away with its "transit without visa" facility many years ago.